# How to customize choice values in radiobuttons within shiny framework

Tags: r, shiny, radio-button

I have developed a shiny app and I am trying to customize the choice values. "Employment" and "Unemployment" values are a subcategory of "in labor force". How can I customize the values in such a way that "employment" and "unemployment" values have a higher/positive indentation? As such, users understand that the "employment" and "unemployment" values are a subcategory of "in labor force".

```
radioButtons(
                                inputId = "Indicator_workforce_",
                                label = strong("Select Indicator:"),
                                selected = "In Labor Force",
                                choices = c ("In Labor Force", "Employment", "Unemployment","Not in Labor Force")),
```

Actual results: [image]

Expected results: [image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to style the actual position of the buttons with CSS.

You can use [conditionalPanel](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.11/conditionalPanel.html) to show the second level options when `In Labor Force` is clicked.

Comment: Thanks; is there any simpler way to only bold the "in labor force" but not "employment" and "unemployment".